# Issue with Vimeo whitelisting (domain specified security) in mobile app implementation

Tags: react-native, vimeo, privacy, whitelist

I have successfully implemented Vimeo domain privacy settings for my web app, allowing me to securely embed videos on authorized domains. However, I'm encountering challenges when trying to retrieve videos by video ID within my mobile app. Specifically, I am encountering issues with video retrieval failures.

My current whitelisting configuration works seamlessly for my web app, and I would like to extend the same level of security and control to my mobile app.

If there are specific steps, I need to take to ensure proper whitelisting for mobile app implementation, please advise me accordingly.